# How can I simplify the following equation for differentiation

Tags: derivatives, optimization, summation

I want to bring the below equation into differentiable form when $k = n-1$ so that I can differential it w.r.t $p$ to get the optimal value of $Ps$ (using differential method).

$P_s = p(1-p) \sum^{k-1}_{i=0} {{n-2} \choose {i}} p^i (1-p)^{n-2-i} $

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the sum goes from $i=0$ to $k-1$? Not to $n-1$?

Comment: what do you mean by "differentiable form"? We have a sum of polinomials, which are straight forward to differentiate. Maybe finding the extremum afterwards is more tricky, but getting the differential is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Could you use $$1=(p+1-p)^{n-2}=\sum^{n-2}_{i=0} {{n-2} \choose {i}} p^i (1-p)^{n-2-i}$$

Comment: Binomial theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem